# Combine columns, align by value, fill NA when values do not match

Tags: r

This is surprisingly difficult. I tried `full_join` and `bind_cols` and `merge` variants, but I can't quite get this to work.

I have:

```
> (t1 <- data.frame(x = letters[10:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  x
1 j
2 i
3 h
4 g
5 f
6 e
7 d
8 c
```

and:

```
> (t2 <- data.frame(y = letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  y
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

I think what I'm looking for is some type of `full_join` that keeps both columns and does set operations, because I want to return this:

```
> data.frame(
+   x = c(letters[10:3], NA, NA),
+   y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, letters[4:1])
+ )
      x    y
1     j <NA>
2     i <NA>
3     h <NA>
4     g <NA>
5     f <NA>
6     e <NA>
7     d    d
8     c    c
9  <NA>    b
10 <NA>    a
```

So it is like a `full_join`, but retains both columns and fills NAs where there are differences. For instance, this just gives me the one column:

```
> full_join(t1, t2, by = c("x" = "y"))
   x
1  j
2  i
3  h
4  g
5  f
6  e
7  d
8  c
9  a
10 b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also find `union` and `match`

```
inds <- union(t1$x, t2$y)
data.frame(x = t1$x[match(inds, t1$x)], y = t2$y[match(inds, t2$y)])

#      x    y
#1     j <NA>
#2     i <NA>
#3     h <NA>
#4     g <NA>
#5     f <NA>
#6     e <NA>
#7     d    d
#8     c    c
#9  <NA>    a
#10 <NA>    b
```

Answer (score 3):

A little hacky, but this works:

```
full_join(
  left_join(t1, t2 %>% mutate(x = y)),
  left_join(t2, t1 %>% mutate(y = x))
)

      x    y
1     j <NA>
2     i <NA>
3     h <NA>
4     g <NA>
5     f <NA>
6     e <NA>
7     d    d
8     c    c
9  <NA>    a
10 <NA>    b
```